# Djongo DB of MongoDB crashed suddenly in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, djongo

I was using MongoDB as my Backend Database which was working perfectly today until now!. I didn't make any changes, yet suddenly every time i run server, I get this error. can't even debug what's the issue here. I really haven't made any change in Django yet this is happening.

**please help me figure this out!**

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 808, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 166, in __iter__
    for doc in cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1238, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1130, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1935, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1883, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1921, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 520, in get_server_session
    session_timeout = self._check_session_support()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 504, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 218, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-02.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: ,ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-00.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: ,ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-01.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: , Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62fd16f8972a661b8168f504, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-00.bppaqzd.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-00.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: ')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-01.bppaqzd.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-01.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: ')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-02.bppaqzd.mongodb.net', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-qk5nrrk-shard-00-02.bppaqzd.mongodb.net:27017: ')>]>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 65, in fetchmany
    ret.append(self.result.next())
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 797, in __next__
    result = next(self._result_generator)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 830, in __iter__
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = %(0)s LIMIT 21
Params: (1,)
Version: 1.3.6
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: None
        Params: None
        Version: None

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run        
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\py\projects\Django\Whatsapp\whatsapp\App\models.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Profile(models.Model):
  File "E:\py\projects\Django\Whatsapp\whatsapp\App\models.py", line 14, in Profile
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User.objects.get(id=1).id)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 646, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1428, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1928, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1928, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meraz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User.objects.get(id=1).id)
```

In the above line you have mentioned OneToOneField but in default attribute field you are providing a constant which means you are trying to use it as a Foreign key which is why I guess it is causing this error.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User.objects.get(id=1).id)
```

Try this and it may work

and if you wanna use it as a OneToOneField only then provide a unique default value everytime you are trying to create an entry into this field.

Comment: i removed the default & deleted all users in the databae. then tried Makemigrations, but it's still causing an error